# Binding SelectedItem of ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, selecteditem

hi i have one list box that every row contain one textbox and one button;

with click button that row delete from listbox; this work with mvvm pattern

i use command for this.

this is my xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryTemplate">
    <Border Width="400" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" CornerRadius="4">

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Width="300" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
            <Button Name="btnDeleteCategory" Width="50" Margin="5"   
              Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="-"   />
        </StackPanel>

    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" Name="lstCategory"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryTemplate}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetAllCategories}">

</ListBox>
```

and in viewmodel class i have this command :

```
private ObjectButtonCommand<Category> _deleteCommand;
public ObjectButtonCommand<Category> DeleteCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _deleteCommand
          ?? (_deleteCommand = new ObjectButtonCommand<Category>(
            _category =>
            {
                GetAllCategories.Remove(_category);

            }));
    }
}
```

that GetAllCategories is observecollection propert;

and this is my ObjectButtonCommand code:

```
public class ObjectButtonCommand<T> : ICommand
    where T:class
{
    private Action<T> WhatToExecute;

    public ObjectButtonCommand(Action<T> What)
    {
        WhatToExecute = What;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        WhatToExecute((T)parameter);
    }
}
```

now every thing is ok and when click button that row delete;

now i want that this process repeat when i select one row of listbox

i try this code :

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" Name="lstCategory" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetAllCategories}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems,ElementName=lstCategory}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

but i get this error at this code : WhatToExecute((T)parameter);

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection' to type 'Sepand.WPFProject.Model.Model.Category'."}

what should i do?

Comment: `_deleteCommand` should be `readonly`. Also, format your question properly next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the selection to the delete command which is a list, hence you cannot use the same command for both cases unless you would wrap the individual items (as passed from the `DataTemplate`) in a list first.

You should probably define a new command which takes an `IList` as parameter (type of `ListBox.SelectedItems`), whose items you then cast to `Category` and remove individually.

If you just want to delete a single selected item you need to change the binding to `SelectedItem` and need be able to handle the case of `SelectedItem` being `null` in your existing command. e.g. change `CanExecute` to `parameter != null` if that is respected by `InvokeCommandAction`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mohammad can you try this:

For your `Listbox`, make sure your `SelectionMode` is set to `Single`.  Then change that you refer to `SelectedItem` in the `CommandParameter` instead of `SelectedItems`.  Like so:

```
                <ListBox Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" Name="lstCategory" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetAllCategories}" SelectionMode="Single">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,ElementName=lstCategory}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </ListBox>
```

Comment: now i get this error {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity"}

Comment: look closely at the stack trace and the line number.  Go back into your code to that point and try and determine what is null.  You are likely running LINQ on a deleted object.  But without all of the code and a full stack trace, its impossible to troubleshoot here.  Feel free to change your question to include more code and be as clear as possible and more people will try and help.